# Видимость приложения на панели, запущенное на втором рабочем столе

Tags: linux, debian, kde

Здравствуйте.
Стоит debi9.2, kde4.14.26. В системе 2 рабочих стола.
Запуска на первом firefox, на втором leafpad.
Но на панели задач, будь я на первом или втором рабочем столе, видны обе программы и firefox, и leafpad. Как сделать, чтобы находясь на первом рабочем столе на панели задач отображался только firefox, а переключившись на второй рабочий стол на панели задач отображался только leafpad?